# Java regular expression for validating a number greater than 20000

Tags: java, regex, validation, numbers

I have a requirement where I want to validate a number which should be greater than 20000 and less than 100000. Please help in providing the regex. I am very new to regular expressions. I have a regular expression for checking whether a number is less than 20000

```
[1-9]\d{0,3}|1\d{4}|20000
```

Comment: Why do you need regex? `(value > min) && (value < max)`

Comment: ^I'm with @hwnd you don't need regex for this sort of thing

Comment: [2-9]{1}(?!0000)[0-9]{4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!20000)[2-9][0-9]{4}$
```

All the numbers you need are 5 digit long. First digit could be from 2-9, every other digit could be anything, just you can't have 20000 in your list in this range. Let's rule out that 1 number with negative look-ahead (?!20000) and let's say first digit could be only 2-9, should follow 4 digits, but those digits could be anything. 
https://regex101.com/r/wY6lA9/1

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a school assignment, then you shouldn't be asking on here.  If you're doing this for a real program, it's much better to parse it to an `int` (or perhaps a `double` if you're allowing non-integer values), and just check if it's in the range you want:

```
try {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(in)
    if (x <= 20000 || x >= 100000) {
        //do what you want here for when it's not valid
    } else {
        //do what you want for a valid input here
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //Do something in case it's not a valid number here
}
```

Now, this assumes you have an input of type `String`.  If it's already a numeric type, then you don't need to parse it - just do the `if-else` clause.